# Updating a single entity without affecting its dependencies in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Consider the following scenario:

I have a Person entity that has a many-to-many relationship with Group entity and a many-to-many relationship with Role entity. Both entities have bidirectional relationship with Person setting CascadeType to SAVE_UPDATE. The FetchType is set to LAZY.

Person also has attributes like name, birthdate, id, etc.

Since I'm working in a heavy transactional multithreaded environment, as a design consideration, when a certain Person attribute is going to be modified, the Person object retrieved through hibernate session's get method is being copied using the following method:

```
    public Person personCopyWithoutDependencies(Person entity){
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setId(entity.getId());
        person.setName(entity.getName());
        person.setBirthdate(entity.getBirthdate());
        person.setGroups(null);
        person.setRoles(null);
        return copy;
    }
```

Then, I do Person's specific attribute modification in the copy object and then call the Hibernate session's Update method. The copy is done to prevent issues with multiple sessions in multiple threads (when doing a modification sessionFactory.openSession() is called and closed after commit while when retrieving an objtect sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() is being called).

If the person object that I modified had previously associated Group and Role entities, it deletes the relationship in the database.

I want to know if it's possible to do the modification I'm intending without losing its relationships.

Thank you very much in advance. Any advice is welcome.

Comment: "The copy is done to prevent issues with multiple sessions in multiple threads" - I don't understand that. This reads like you trying to solve problems that Hibernate should be solving for you.

Comment: Since FetchType is set to LAZY, when having problems with sessions is common to get the following exception: "failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.package.Entity, could not initialize proxy - no Session"

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this, is to validate, whats changed, and retrieve REal Hibernate object back.

Steps:

1. You do have a copy with some attributes. (NULL instead of Proxy lazy collections)
2. You do change some of them.
3. You retrieve Real object again from Hibernate (DB)
4. You map objects attributes back to real object, and just do not do this for NULL attributes.
5. commit changes.

This is the only way to do this. As @Gimbly mentioned, you are trying to handle, whats Hibernate suppose to do.